# Equivalent tool in WPF to the WinForm BindingNavigator tool

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, visual-studio-2010

In a WinForm I've used a BindingNavigator out of the toolbox.

I'm moving the application to a WPF. There isn't a BindingNavigator in the toolbox, or in the Extended WPF Toolkit.

The WPF is very simple with a couple of Textboxes that display information from a couple of fields in the data but I'd like a way of scrolling through the records one at a time.

What is the WPF alternative to the BindingNavigator?

Comment: Use google to find these kind of answers.  Type "wpf bindingnavigator" in the query box, take the first hit.

Comment: I think Hans is trying to say `WhyTheQ` when there are 175,000 google matches and the top google result has all the info on the subject :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More involved than the out-of-the-box WinFrom BindingNavigator but potentially more powerful.

Christian Nagel's blog has the following two articles:

1. [BindingNavigator for WPF (Part 1 - Creating)](http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cnagel/2010/08/bindingnavigator-for-wpf-part-1---creating.html)
2. [BindingNavigator for WPF (Part 2–Using)](http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cnagel/2010/08/bindingnavigator-for-wpf-part-2using.html)